# how to attach or detach record on many to many sequelize association?

Tags: node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have many to many association like this following model:

```
const Movie = sequelize.define('Movie', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const Actor = sequelize.define('Actor', { name: DataTypes.STRING });
const ActorMovies = sequelize.define('ActorMovies', {
  MovieId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Movie, 
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  ActorId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: Actor,
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
});
Movie.belongsToMany(Actor, { through: ActorMovies });
Actor.belongsToMany(Movie, { through: ActorMovies });
```

And I succsessfully create `Movie` when create an `Actor` record with this following code:

```
Actor.create({
  name: 'Jhony',
  movies: [
    { name: 'Movie 1'}, // it will generate Movie with ID 1
    { name: 'Movie 2'} // it will generate Movie with ID 2
  ]
}, {
  include: [ Movie ]
})
```

but my question how can I attach multiple existing `Movie` record when creating an `Actor`?
I already try:

```
Actor.create({
  name: 'Edward',
  movieIds: [1, 2]
}, {
  include: [ Movie ]
})
```

and:

```
Actor.create({
      name: 'Edward',
      movies: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
    }, {
      include: [ Movie ]
    })
```

But stil didn't work. Anyone can help me, please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't link existing movies to a new actor while creating it. You need to call `setMovies` of the new actor model instance:

```js
const actor = await Actor.create({
  name: 'Edward',
}) 
await actor.setMovies([1, 2])
```

Also, please pay attention that if you execute more than one query that changes something in DB it would be much more reliable to use transactions to turn all this queries into one atomic operation.